# How to add multiple selection mode in listview getting data from JSON

Tags: android, android-listview

I am fetching data into listview using JSON, but now i need to make my listview to allow user to select multiple item and showing add to order button at the bottom, once user has done with checkbox selections and now want to make that order just need to click on add to order button, once user will click on button then selected ListView Items, i am sending to next activity using Intent namely ResultActivity, but whenever i run my app getting Unfortunately app has stopped and Logcat says:

```
   10-19 12:56:56.812: D/dalvikvm(709): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 3% free 8069K/8259K, paused 43ms, total 45ms
10-19 12:56:56.812: I/dalvikvm-heap(709): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.514MB for 614416-byte allocation
10-19 12:56:56.882: D/dalvikvm(709): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 8668K/8903K, paused 23ms+4ms, total 70ms
10-19 12:56:56.932: D/dalvikvm(709): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 8668K/8903K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
10-19 12:56:56.964: I/dalvikvm-heap(709): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.832MB for 1382416-byte allocation
10-19 12:56:57.043: D/dalvikvm(709): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 10018K/10311K, paused 36ms+5ms, total 83ms
10-19 12:56:57.293: D/gralloc_goldfish(709): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-19 12:57:00.862: D/AndroidRuntime(709): Shutting down VM
10-19 12:57:00.862: W/dalvikvm(709): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct/com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.TabSample}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct/com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct/com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.TabSample.addTab(TabSample.java:48)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.TabSample.setTabs(TabSample.java:27)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.TabSample.onCreate(TabSample.java:23)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  ... 11 more
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-19 12:57:00.924: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  ... 23 more
```

MainActivity.java:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener {
    Button button;
ListView lview3;
ListViewCustomAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Object> itemList;
private ItemBean bean;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    prepareArrayLits();
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, itemList);
    lview3.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

    lview3.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

private void findViewsById() {
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    SparseBooleanArray checked = lview3.getCheckedItemPositions();
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            selectedItems.add((String) adapter.getItem(position));
    }
    String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ResultActivity.class);

    // Create a bundle object
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

    // Add the bundle to the intent.
    intent.putExtras(b);

    // start the ResultActivity
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

ResultActivity.java:-

```
   public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.outputList);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultArr);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activitymain:-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Add to Order" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp" 
    android:layout_above="@id/submit"
    >

</ListView>
```

TabSample:-

```
   public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabmain);
        setTabs() ;
    }
    private void setTabs()
    {
        addTab("Menu", R.drawable.tab_home, MainActivity.class);
        addTab("Offers", R.drawable.tab_search, MainActivity.class);

        addTab("Location", R.drawable.tab_home, ArrowsActivity.class);
        addTab("Reservation", R.drawable.tab_search, ReservationActivity.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your TabSample class.......and what are line no 48,27,23 in that????????

Comment: TabSample activity consists only 31 lines, title.setText(labelId);=23line

Comment: friend if you haven't edited your code then there must be line 48.... your logs are saying that TabSample.addTab(TabSample.java:48)......or if you have edited then also edit your logs.

Comment: if you are not able to view line number then go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show line numbers.